given N sequences and a consensus, count how many sequences agree with the consensus per position
I have 3 aligned sequences and a consensus sequences:
aln_seqs <- c('CCCGNGGGAGANAGACTGAGTCTGTGATATACACATCAGAATCCTTACTTTGTGACACATTTGTTTGAGA','CCCGGGGGAGAAAGNTTT-GTCTGTGATATACACATCAGAATCCTTACTTTGTGACACATTTGTTTGAGA','---ACGGGGNTGNAGTTGTGTCTGTGATATACACATCAGAATCCTTACTTTGTGACACATTTGTTTGAGA')
cons_seq <- 'CCCG?GGGAGA?AG?TTG?GTCTGTGATATACACATCAGAATCCTTACTTTGTGACACATTTGTTTGAGA'

I just want to count how many of the 3 sequences agree with the consensus per position.
I started like this:
cons_call <- unlist(strsplit(cons_seq, ""))
seqs_calls <- sapply(aln_seqs, strsplit, "")
df <- as.data.frame(seqs_calls)
names(df) <- paste0('seq',1:length(aln_seqs))
df$cons <- cons_call

df looks like this:
> df
   seq1 seq2 seq3 cons
1     C    C    -    C
2     C    C    -    C
3     C    C    -    C
4     G    G    A    G
5     N    G    C    ?
6     G    G    G    G
7     G    G    G    G
8     G    G    G    G
9     A    A    G    A
10    G    G    N    G
...

Now I want to add an extra count column that shows how many sequence agree with the consensus per position. For example, for position 1 it would be 2 out of 3, for position 5 it would be 0 out of 3, for position 6 3 out of 3... and so on.
How shall I calculate this count given the above df? Or is a simpler way without creating df? Thanks

Try rowSums(df[1:3] == df$cons)

Can also do rowSums(matrix(unlist(strsplit(aln_seqs, ""), use.names = FALSE), ncol=length(aln_seqs))==unlist(strsplit(cons_seq, ""), use.names = FALSE))
